# Передача шаблонной функции в for_each

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl

Выдает ошибку при попытке передать в функцию for_each, третьим параметром, шаблон функции. Помогите разобраться.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void display(T a){
     cout << a;
}

void main(){
     setlocale(0, "russian");

     ifstream in("text.txt");
     vector<int> vectr;

     int i;
     while(!in.eof()){
        in >> i;
        vectr.push_back(i);
     }

    for_each(vectr.begin(), vectr.end(), display);
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Компилятор пишет, что нельзя использовать шаблон функции в качестве параметра. Почему нельзя использовать? И как это обойти?

```
 `error C2896: '_Fn1 std::for_each(_InIt,_InIt,_Fn1)' : cannot use function 
  template 'void display(T)' as a function argument

  see declaration of 'display'

  error C2784: '_Fn1 std::for_each(_InIt,_InIt,_Fn1)' : could not deduce 
  template 
  argument for '_InIt' from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>'
         with
         [
              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<int,std::allocator<int>>
         ]

  algorithm(28) : see declaration of 'std::for_each'
```

`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Самая важная для вас часть ошибки звучит так:

> could not deduce template argument for ...

Это означает, что компилятор не смог выполнить неявное выведения типа шаблонного параметра для `void display<T>(T a)`. Надо ему немного в этом помочь:

```
for_each(vectr.begin(), vectr.end(), display<int>);
```

---

Теперь разберёмся, почему компилятор не смог вывести тип самостоятельно.

Дело в том, что сигнатура функции `std::foreach` [объявлена](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) *слишком абстрактной*:

```
template <class InputIterator, class Function>
    Function for_each (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function fn);
```

Тип функции никак не завязан на типе итераторов. В придачу, нет никакой опережающей проверки типа аргумента функтора `Function` на уровне шаблонного объявления. Вот из-за этой независимости компилятор и не знает, как соотнести `Function` с `display<T>()`. Будь метод объявлен так:

```
template <class InputIterator, class Ret>
    Function for_each (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Ret(*fn)(std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type));
```

компилятор смог бы применить *type deduction* и подставить шаблонный аргумент функции: `Ret(*)(std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type)` ⟶ `Ret(*)(int)` ⟷ `void(*)(int)`.

Но для подобных манёвров необходимо было бы определять шаблонные перегрузки для всех типов функторов (навскидку: свободные функции, методы классов и функциональные классы (те, которые с `operator()`)). То есть ради возможности опустить `<int>` нам необходимо усложнить стандартную библиотеку.

Comment: Добавлю, что функциональные объекты лишены такой проблемы. Стоит сделать `auto display_f = [](auto&& a) { display(a); };` и `display_f`можно передавать в `for_each`